# lattice of subgroups - Galois Theory

Tags: galois-theory

If $f(x) = x^{10} + 1$, what would my lattice of subgroups of the group Gal(L/Q) look like where $L$ is a complex splitting field of f(x) over $\mathbb{Q}$.

This is more out of curiosity as I self study Galois Theory.

Comment: What is your splitting field?

Comment: What have you already done yourself? Do you know what the splitting field of $f$ is? Do you know what the Galois group itself is? Where exactly are you stuck? Or do you for some reason just need the lattice, or do you also wish to know how to compute it? For what it's worth: the Galois group is ${\mathbb Z}/4 \times {\mathbb Z}/2$.

Comment: I just wanted to see the lattis. I know there is 10 roots with 2 of them being in the complex numbers.

Comment: Please don't remove the original question like this. It makes everybody else's comments (and eventual answers) look out of place.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just the lattice then. This should be a *hint*, but I don't think I can put images in a comment. I'll leave it to the OP to figure out what subgroups of ${\mathbb Z}/4 \times {\mathbb Z}/2$ go where, what the Galois group is in terms of automorphisms of $L$ (or in terms of the roots of $f$), and what the corresponding lattice of subfields of $L$ is.

[image: Subgroup lattice of Gal(x^10+1)]